Filling in a hole through concrete screed floor
The floor of one of my sheds is concrete screed and so is suitable for conversion to a more habitable space. The issue I currently have is that within this space, the previous owner dug a 1m³ hole to fit a climbing frame into.
I'd like to fill this hole in and restore it to match the surrounding concrete screed. How can I do this? The hole currently floods during the winter due to seepage through the concrete blocks lining it.
My current plan is to fill the hole with a sub-base, lay a damp proof course and then pour concrete screed on top. Is this the correct course of action? As this hole currently floods, will this result in damp due to the DPC only covering the hole and not being sealed at the edges?

What do you mean by "screed?"

put in drain rock/uncompressible fill, put down poly, match slab thickness.
